# eCommerce platform with Bitcoin support?

Tags: cms, ecommerce, self-hosted, bitcoin

I'm looking for an eCommerce solution that has the following specs:

- Self-hosted
- Written in Node.js, or PHP/HTML (not Python or Ruby)
- Supports simple theming, addons, and different product types
- Has simple installation
- Has a messaging system
- Supports custom home page
- Escrow support

For the Bitcoin part, there's a huge requirement: no external payment processors. I wish to set up an anonymous marketplace where people can purchase (digital) goods without giving up their anonimity.

For this I thought of two possible systems:

- Have a central BTC wallet, and have addresses generated for users to send in their Bitcoin (which appears like store credit, from what they can do the purchases, and request it to be sent back).
- Have a central BTC wallet, but generate addresses for each purchase. Monitor that address, and when the BTC arrives (either in one or in parts), mark the purchase paid (like a credit card purchase).

It would be important to generate the addresses purchase or user-specific.

Currently the only solution I found was to use a WordPress plugin by [Bitcoin Way](http://www.bitcoinway.com). But I'd rather not use WordPress as it could have a backdoor (like it had in the past) which could de-anonymize the users.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at https://www.openbazaar.org/ We are now 2.5 years later so things have evolved most probably in the right direction for you.